# Need some help in serialization

Tags: c++, c, unix

I am trying to write a program to serialize a linked list to a file without using any libraries. My problem is how to add or remove nodes to the serialized structure since I dont have next pointer ? Also how can I avoid fragmentation ?

Comment: I am trying to serialize a linkedlist structure. Can someone help me how to do this. No external library please. The serialize should work for adding nodes and deleting nodes in the files. Also how to convert a struture to binary and then to a linkedlist. (also there are "next" pointers). Also in what format should I store it so that my file can save multiple linkedlists.

Comment: @mousey : we've been over this :)  What don't you understand about our discussion?

Comment: @Stephen I didnt get the format of storing it. If I want to store a linked lists involving int data . Do I need to store the value like {int value and file offset of the next structure ?) or How do I maintain the structure format in the file

Comment: @mousey : added an illustration.  Give it a try, then come back with specific questions.

Comment: @Stephen so my format of the file should be like 23 4 1 8 19 -1 ? where 4 8 are offsets and my offset should be size of the data right ?

Comment: @mousey : Your offset should tell you _where_ to read the next item.  Either by index in the file, or file offset.

Comment: @Stephen If I want to store many linkedlist what is the best way of storing ? Nodes are being added and removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your linked list doesn't have loops, then the fact that this is a "linked list" is a memory detail, not a serialization detail.  Just write the node values out into the file and build the `next` pointers when you deserialize.

However, if your linked list *does* have loops, then you'll need something smarter.  You'll need to store `next` pointers as a file offsets to the node (or something similar) to encode the "link".

For each node in your linked list, store two words.  The first is the data, the second is the offset of the `next` node.  Here is an illustration of the circularly linked list:

```
 +-> 1234 -> 5678 -> 2398 -+
 |                         |
 +-------------------------+


0  : 4bytes: 1234 : int data  <------------+
4  : 4bytes:    8 : offset of next node -+ |
                                         | |
8  : 4bytes: 5678 : int data  <----------+ |
12 : 4bytes:   16 : offset of next node -+ |
                                         | |
16 : 4bytes: 2398 : int data  <----------+ |
20 : 4bytes:    0 : offset of next node ---+
```

Comment: @mousey : You could sort them before serializing.  Typically, you don't want your serialization routines to modify your data.  In other words, you want `A == Deserialize(Serialize(A))`.  If you start changing the order of elements, you're in trouble.

Comment: @Stephen If I add a new element that need to be in sorted order. do I need to deserialize the entire list for adding a new element ?

Comment: @mousey : Probably.  But, typically you don't serialize (and deserialize) every time you add an element to a list.  You usually serialize it to send it over the network, store it on disk, etc.  You may choose a different format altogether if the sorted property (and constant re-encoding) is important - when writing, always append to the back of the file and keep it sorted when you read it back in.

Comment: Also I have an another question. How to store the pointers ?

Comment: since if I store the pointers there is no meaning

Comment: @mousey : A pointer is just an address.  You can't really store the pointers meaningfully. You can store 'pointers' to within the file by using file offsets. For example, `node->next` is at byte234 in the file, so seek there to read it.  However, you'll need to deduplicate these references.  You sound like a beginner, so consider if you really need this behavior.

Comment: No need to use anything as drastic as file offsets. Just a plain sequence number will do. That is, store each node as (conetent, next) where next is simple the number of nodes into the serialized list of the node references. If it hasn't been done yet, give it the next number and do it next. Simple. Trees are a little harder: use the 2n and 2n+1 ordering.

Comment: @dmckee : good call, straight sequence numbers will be easier than offsets.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang : yes... I was changing my example as I wrote it... forgot to update that. thanks.